# How appropriate or inappropriate is the word "papoose" in a Native America song?

Tags: lyrics, folk

I'm researching Native American songs to teach elementary students (approx. 8-9 years old) in a US public elementary school.

I found many songs that have the original lyrics presented phonetically, so that the students can try approximating the original languages.  This is difficult for kids, but important to try so that they can learn the songs as close to their original form as possible.  I also found several that have been translated to English.  This is advantageous too, as kids will understand the songs better and will be able to sing them in context.  I understand that it takes away a little of the authenticity of the song to sing in English but I will trade that for context and simplicity of singing.  I probably will sing a few songs in the original languages and a few songs in English with them.

One word in a translated song gave me pause.  Here are the lyrics:

> Lullaby little papoose, lullaby little papoose;
> Mother is near you, nothing can harm you;
> Lullaby little papoose.

Laura Ingalls Wilder's "Little House" books have been stripped of several of their honors and removed from some school reading lists because of her depictions of Native Americans.  They are frequently seen in her books as a lesser people, and her family frequently says that they wish they were never there.  In particular, I wonder about the word "papoose."  Laura often expresses a wish to have a papoose (a Native American baby) of her own.  She is young at the time, but the sense of the writing is that she would enjoy it as she enjoys playing with her dolls -- as an object.

**Is the word *papoose*, either because of Laura's usage or independent of that, an acceptable word?**  If not, are there suggestions for changing this lyric?

I would probably teach the song by making *little* a three-note slur and placing the word *child* on the half note if *papoose* is deemed unacceptable.  I know that *baby* is a two-sylablle word, but the emphasis would be on the wrong beat.

Here is the song where I found it ([link](https://www.bethsnotesplus.com/2015/12/lullaby-sioux.html)).  EDIT: the owner of that site has shared that the translation comes from Shirley McRae's "American Sampler" (1985).

Comment: The main content of this question is more about language usage than music, so it would probably be a better fit on [English.SE] than here.

Comment: Perhaps, @Michael Seifert , but I think a question about the suitability of a word in a song and how to musically avoid it has several nuances that this community is better-prepared to address.  It seems to me similar to the appropriateness of using dialect in songs, for example.  While it does include a significant aspect of language the musical interpretation is what I'm seeking.

Comment: Sorry, my take is that "is it okay" is a topic for elsewhere, but if so, then "how do I 'patch' the lyrics" is one for here. And my quick take is "I absolutely wouldn't use the word, and I'd put the song on hold until I could learn more about it."

Comment: My longer take: Yes, we want to build a curriculum with sources from many cultures. But it's terribly easy to accidentally do so by decontextualizing or "essentializing" those cultures; my MAT professor referred to it as "Taco Tuesday in the cafeteria." *Is* that actually a Sioux song? From when? History, or still in use today? Documented by whom? Have the pitches or meter been "normalized" to Western practices? Most of all, *who made this translation*? These are the kinds of questions that "Bethsnotesplus.com" isn't going to answer...

Comment: ... This kind of website is a blessing and a curse to music teachers. Here's a handy resource, easily found, but with the depth of scholarship and documentation as your average Facebook conspiracy theory. And yes, there's such a thing as "false authenticity," in which we go hunting for some Pre-Columbian indigenous practice and overlook the lived realities of the Indians sharing our cultural landscape today. When talking *in particular* about Indians, voice and direct representation matter. In cultures predicated on oral (direct person-to-person) transmission of shared knowledge, ...

Comment: ... what's more important than whether we read about them or acquired their cultural artifact is whether we connect with individuals, preferably face-to-face, and hear their story from their own mouth. It would be awesome if you could actually invite a representative of a local tribe into the classroom. Barring that, it would be nice to find a resource that you can actually pinpoint to a particular people, preferably support a surely endangered language by learning the original text, and fight the myth that Indians are a "history topic" by also studying current practices.

Comment: Excellent thoughts, @Andy Bonner !  And yes, these sources are most definitely a blessing and a curse!  And "Taco Tuesday" is a very real problem - how often do we "learn" about another culture just through its food and festivals?

Comment: I went to a talk by Joseph Bruchac at a library once and he said, if you want to know if something is okay, or authentic, call a tribal office and ask the people who know. / Please don't sing part of it in translation, and please don't teach it with some phonetic notation in quasi-English.  Teach the words by letting them listen and imitate.  You can give them the musical notation and you can, in a later stage, give them the lyrics as they would be notated by the relevant tribe.  If you don't want to teach the song in a respectful way, then please skip this project.

Comment: @aparente thank you for the comment.  I am actually already communicating with a local tribe and arranging some time for me to learn from one of their citizens.

Comment: Great!  How about if you just start from scratch and ask if they have any suggestions for songs and teaching approaches you could use with your students?  Perhaps you could bring a video of a sample song your students have learned this semester.  I hope you will report back!

Comment: Yep, I hope to have them join us and teach some songs to the kids directly.  I will say that I can't argue with any of the comments or answers on this post advising me to avoid this particular translation.  It's already been scratched off the list.  The issue of whether or not translations are appropriate in learning music from other cultures is another matter, however.  I believe it has its place, if done respectfully.

Comment: I think you can talk them through the story.  I really don't see why a translation is necessary.  Question: what proportion of your students are bilingual?

Comment: Seems ironic that you're concerned about appropriate language for a "native American" song, looking only at the word "papoose", while the rest of the "native" song is in English! English for a supposed "native" song would be the more likely source of offense. Just use "baby" if the song is in English, or get help to translate the lyrics into an actual language.

Comment: @Michael Curtis it sounds like someone should ask the question, "Is it appropriate to sing a song from another culture in your native language?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic on Music SE site. It's a question about language and culture. I suggest English Language and Usage SE.

Comment: @nuggethead, I would think a lyric translation would not cause any concern, unless it somehow was meant deliberately to offend. I think Aaron's answer gets to the particular problem with this word "papoose." Using it to sprinkle some cultural authenticity on a song without realizing it's a word from a specific language, not some general "native American" language, is the offense. If someone did something like translate a complete English lyric into proper Algonquin, I don't think that would offend. Maybe just not the lyric to _O Canada_!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### "Papoose" is generally offensive, but might be okay in a Narragansett or Algonquin song, as those tribes used the word.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/papoose):

> 1. dated, offensive, see usage paragraph below : an Indigenous baby or young child of North America.

> Usage of Papoose
> The use of papoose in the meaning shown above at sense 1 is regarded as offensive. While use of the term to refer to a style of baby carrier is common, especially in British English, this use is also sometimes regarded as offensive due to its association with sense 1.

Oxford agrees:

> 2. dated, offensive A young North American Indian child.

On the other hand, at least one website regarding [use of Native American language](https://americanindiansinchildrensliterature.blogspot.com/2008/02/papoose.html) has some more nuanced views:

> I don't think it is offensive.  It just isn't used right. (Dr. Debbie Reese)

> "papoose" is a Narragansett word. Narragansett mothers may have used the word, but Native mothers from hundreds of other tribes didn't. They used their own words for "infant."

The effect of using "papoose" for all Native infants is to homogenize hundreds of tribes into one. The same problem occurs with words like chief, brave, and squaw. If these words are universally applicable, then all Native cultures are the same. (Comment by Rob)

> I would have to say that it is offensive unless is is said by a Narragansett person to another Narragansett person. (Comment by Durango Mendoza)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papoose) backs this up:

> Papoose (from the Algonquian papoose, meaning "child") is an American English word whose present meaning is "a Native American child" (regardless of tribe) or, even more generally, any child, usually used as a term of endearment, often in the context of the child's mother. However, the word is considered offensive to many Native Americans whose tribes did not use the word.

#### Substitution options

1. The initial suggestion of extending "little" and then using "child" seems like a good way to go.
2. "Dear one" would work reasonably well. The emphasis is slightly off, but not egregiously so.
3. "Sweetheart" would also work in the same way as "Dear one".
4. Another option would be a larger change to the lyrics: for example, "Lullaby baby so sweet".

Comment: Thank you, @Aaron  This song is purportedly from the Sioux nation, so it would seem to fall into the trap of lumping all Native American cultures into one.  "Child" seems the best option.

Comment: @nuggethead Here is a phonetic translation of a (different) lullaby in the Lakota language: https://lyricstranslate.com/en/lakota-lullaby-lakota-lullaby.html.

Comment: @nuggethead Also, Titon's [*Worlds of Music*](https://www.amazon.com/Worlds-Music-Introduction-Peoples-dp-0534595391/dp/0534595391) includes a Zuni lullaby, discussed in the text and included in the CDs (and uploaded to [Youtube here](https://youtu.be/jHJZlPnp2i8)). Its gentle tonality makes a striking counterpoint to some of the ritual chants that give rise to the "hey ya hey ya" stereotypes of Indian musical idioms.

Comment: @Andy Bonner ha!  Amazon has decided that the book you suggest is now worth $223!  I'll look around for it elsewhere, perhaps.  Does it have accurately notated songs, in your opinion?

Comment: Note that the etymology gives "Algonquian," not "Algonquin," as the source of the word.  For a basic vocabulary word such as this, it's very likely that the word is shared among most or all of the languages in the family, just as most if not all Germanic languages share words such as "man." There are or were dozens of Algonquian languages, originally widespread east of the Rockies, across most of modern-day Canada and in the US central Western plains, Midwest, Mid-Atlantic, and New England. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algonquian_languages. Lakota is a Siouxan language, a distinct family.

Comment: I have to say, though, that even in a song that is originally from a language with some form of the word "papoose," it may or may not be offensive to use the word in the English translation, depending on how and why the word is used, so "might be okay" is probably the right way to put it.  If I were considering using a song with the word in it, I would also consider asking some people from Native American communities for their opinions.  I wouldn't want to offend, but rejecting an opportunity to represent their cultural heritage, or to be enriched by their cultural heritage, is also harmful.

Comment: @phoog Your comment makes me notice that Wikipedia is confusing on the point of which language(s) used "papoose". The quotation I used specifies "Algonquian", but that word links to "Algonquin", begging the question of whether there's a typo or an incorrect link in the entry.